# How does gcm.register("Sender_id") work?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to test `gcm.register("Sender_ID")` where

`gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);` and `this` is a context.

When I call it in airplane mode with a "Sender_ID" I've used before, it immediately shoots back the Registration ID. However, when I use a random Sender_ID, it throws an IOException.

I would not expect the behavior of it knowing the Registration ID for Senders that it already registered for. I expected an IOException for both. Does it use a cache?

I'm still going to store the RegistrationID in a preference, but this functionality yields itself to people potentially just calling `gcm.register("Sender_ID")` to retrieve the phones Registration ID instead of storing it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

From reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#register(java.lang.String...)), you can see that once registered, repeated calls to the `register()` method will return the original reg_Id (which seems to be stored in SharedPreferences).

In order to reregister for same sender ID, user needs to call the `unregister()` method of `gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);`

Hope this clarified your questions.